# Why is $\theta$$ = $$\theta$$_{2}$ and not Phi in this Magnetic Field due to Current in Loop Equation

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, distance

I'm wondering how we know that  $\theta$ =  $\theta$$_{2}$ (essential to solving the problem) and that it is not equal to, for example, ϕ?

[image]

Comment: Couldn't you have a neater diagram ?

Comment: It's very hard to see what $\theta$ and $\theta_2$ are even supposed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angle $\theta$ you drew is wrong. For the given current loop, the magnetic field will be at an angle of $\theta$ relative to the vertical axis, and in the plane containing the axis of the loop. Your angle as drawn seems to be relative to some $B$ that appears to point along $y$.

See this diagram (looking from the side, with the current element at the top of the ring):

[image]